# If else inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi How can I do this inside an array. I want REMARKS to display the word "Stopped" when speed is less then 10Kph

Here's my code

```
array(
                  'account' => $rowmaxtec['ACCOUNT'],
                  'trxdate' => $rowmaxtec['TRXDATE'],
                  //'trxtime' => date('H:i:s',strtotime("+8 Hours",strtotime($rowmaxtec['gpsdate'] . ' ' . $rowmaxtec['gpstime']))),
                 // 'trxtime' => $gpsdatetimeg,
                 'trxtime' => $philtime,
                  'long' => $rowmaxtec['LONG'],
                  'lat' => $rowmaxtec['LAT'],
                  'location' => callback($rowmaxtec['LOCATION']),
                  'direction' => $rowmaxtec['DIRECTION'],
                  'compass' => $rowmaxtec['COMPASS'],
                  'id' => $rowmaxtec['ID'],
                  'events' => $rowmaxtec['Events'],
                  'remarks' => $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'],    -----------------------REMARKS
                  'status' => $rowmaxtec['devicestatus'],
                  'kmrun' => $kmrun,
                  'speed' => $rowmaxtec['speed'],          <------if this is  less than 10kph then REMARKS must be masked/overwritten by the word Stopped
                  'totalkm' => $total,
        'engine' => $rowmaxtec['ENGINE']
                  );
```

So Sorry because this is the first time I will do an if else statement inside an array.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: `//'remarks' => $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'],
                      'status' => $rowmaxtec['devicestatus'],
                      'kmrun' => $kmrun,
                      //'speed' => $rowmaxtec['speed'],
                      if ($rowmaxtec['speed'] <=10) {
                         'remarks' => 'Stopped',
                       } 
                       else
                       {
                          'remarks' => $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'],                        
                       },`

Comment: what would be the value of `$rowmaxtec['speed']` ? just 10 or including 'kph' part ?

Answer (score 10):

Use ternary operator

```
'remarks' => ($rowmaxtec['speed'] < 10) ? 'Stopped' : $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'],
```

`$rowmaxtec['speed'] < 10` could be replaced by a function if you've to deal with the format of `$rowmaxtec['speed']` (i.e if it's not a simple integer)

Quick example if you consider '10Kph' :

```
function speed_check ($speed, $check_value = 10) {
   return substr($speed, 0, -3) < $check_value;
}

'remarks' => (speed_check($rowmaxtec['speed'])) ? 'Stopped' : $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'],
```

Comment: Change semicolon to coma :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using if shorthands to write it all inline:

```
'remarks' => (($rowmaxtec['speed'] < 10)?"STOP":$rowmaxtec['remarks'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a shorthand if:

```
$rowmaxtec['speed'] <= 10 ? "STOPPED" : $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'];
```

More information here:

http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

So:

```
array(
              'account' => $rowmaxtec['ACCOUNT'],
              'trxdate' => $rowmaxtec['TRXDATE'],
              //'trxtime' => date('H:i:s',strtotime("+8 Hours",strtotime($rowmaxtec['gpsdate'] . ' ' . $rowmaxtec['gpstime']))),
             // 'trxtime' => $gpsdatetimeg,
             'trxtime' => $philtime,
              'long' => $rowmaxtec['LONG'],
              'lat' => $rowmaxtec['LAT'],
              'location' => callback($rowmaxtec['LOCATION']),
              'direction' => $rowmaxtec['DIRECTION'],
              'compass' => $rowmaxtec['COMPASS'],
              'id' => $rowmaxtec['ID'],
              'events' => $rowmaxtec['Events'],
              'remarks' => $rowmaxtec['speed'] <= 10 ? "STOPPED" : $rowmaxtec['REMARKS'],    -----------------------REMARKS
              'status' => $rowmaxtec['devicestatus'],
              'kmrun' => $kmrun,
              'speed' => $rowmaxtec['speed'],
              'totalkm' => $total,
    'engine' => $rowmaxtec['ENGINE']
              );
```